# Delete Windows and Reinstall on SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation

I just build my computer. However, I accidentally installed Windows 10 (and upgraded to pro) on the HDD instead of the SSD. I don't need any of the files or anything on the HDD. I would like to delete everything off the HDD and install windows on the SSD. How can I do this? Will my product key work another time?

HDD - https://pcpartpicker.com/product/2Qqbt6/western-digital-internal-hard-drive-wd30ezrz

SSD - https://pcpartpicker.com/product/JLdxFT/samsung-970-evo-10tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-mz-v7e1t0baw

Comment: Call a friend who has done this before? It isn't that complicated, but plenty that you can do wrong. I would disconnect the HDD and install on the SSD and activate that new installations. Call Microsoft if activation does not work. Then clean out the HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a "clean install of Windows 10" and it got me the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Microsoft licences are only available for one device, so as one disk is considered as one device, you probably won't be able to use the licence again with another hard drive.

I would say that you can use the app of Windows 10: "Get help from Microsoft" and create a new case for them, for the case they could do something for you.

And, in the case they don't, you probably would need to buy a new licence key, if you really want to go through the legal way.